# VBA code to match cell value to column heading and return cell value in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

I've been trying to piece this together but have been unsuccessful so far.

Workbook2, with sheet name "Sheet1" has the data which needs to be pulled into Workbook1, with sheet name "DATA".

Workbook 2:

```
Student ID    Date completed   Question#  Score
101            12/10/2018        1         0
101            12/10/2018        2         5
101            12/10/2018        3         10
101            12/10/2018        4         0
102            12/05/2018        1         10
102            12/05/2018        2         0
```

Workbook 1:

```
Student ID  Date Completed  Question1  2   3   4
101         12/10/2018       0         5   10  0
102         12/05/2018       10        0
```

What I'm trying to do is get the code to loop through the column with the Question # (in "Sheet1" Workbook 2), and if the student numbers match, and if the question number in Workbook 2 matches the column heading in Sheet "DATA" (Workbook 1) then return the student number, date completed and most importantly, the score value under the matching column heading.

The code I've been trying to use is below. Any suggestions would be welcome:

```
Public Sub grabqdata()


Dim wbmacro As Workbook
Dim wblean As Workbook

Set wbmacro = Workbooks.Item("MacroFile.xlsm")
Set wblean = Workbooks.Item("Workbook2.xlsx")

Dim wsmacro As Worksheet
Dim wslean As Worksheet

Set wsmacro = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Data")
Set wslean = wblean.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")

Dim leanrange As Range
Set leanrange = wslean.Range("A2:A150000")

Dim headerrange As Range
Set headerrange = wsmacro.Range("A1:G1")

Dim qrange As Range
Set qrange = wslean.Range("D2:D150000")

Dim macrorange As Range
Set macrorange = wsmacro.Range("A:A")

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim colm As Long
colm = WorksheetFunction.Match(wsmacro, Range("A1:G1"), 0)


Dim cell As Range


i = 1


For Each cell In leanrange

    If leanrange.Range("A2") = macrorange.Range("a2") Then


        wsmacro.Range("C2").Offset(i, 0) = wslean.Range("D2").Offset(i, 0)


        i = i + 1
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Column C is where the first Q# is (so Q1 or "1").

Thank you!

Comment: You could just put it all in a pivot table and remove the need for any VBA.

Comment: i have to use vba unfortunately as this expands in the future. just trying to figure out how :)

Comment: If it must be VBA, I would go with an array

Comment: FYI, those `Item`are implicit. Everybody writes `wbmacro.Worksheets("Data")`.

Comment: how would i go about doing this with an array?

Comment: Paste whole range from WB2 into array1. Using advanced filter, copy unique values from WB2 to WB1 (1st column). Paste unique into array2. Forget about WB2, everything you need is in arrays. Then a little dancing (hours) to create array3, which is then pasted into WB1.

Comment: I would approach this differently.  Making a list of unique student numbers and working through that list one by one your data.  Building one student at a time.  I might be able to help you on this later.

Comment: @VBAWARD Does it matter what order the question numbers are? Will there always be an answer for every question? Is there a chance there could be the same student ID twice but with a different date completed?

Comment: the order of the questions doesn't really matter. the "DATA" sheet has them ordered sequentially, thats all. thats why i'm trying to get the cell to match the column heading in case the source sheet (shee1) has it out of order. there will always be an answer for every question. and there will not be a different date completed.

Comment: @VBasic2008. that sounds complicated lol. im still pretty new to VBA and figuring my way out :) any material you could send my way that i could use as a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the prettiest, but this should get the job done... This also makes some assumptions, like there aren't multiple completed dates for the same student ID (needed clarification) - also assumes that every student goes through the same question #s (1, 2, 3, etc.).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol, foundrow As Long, foundcol As Long

Set sht = Workbooks("Testfile1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Workbooks("Testfile2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

sht2.Cells.ClearContents
sht2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Student ID"
sht2.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Date completed"
sht2.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Question # 1"
k = 2

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Application.CountIf(sht2.Range("A:A"), sht.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 Then
        sht2.Cells(k, 1).Value = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
        sht2.Cells(k, 2).Value = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value

        lastcol = sht2.Cells(1, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        sht2.Cells(k, 3).Value = sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        k = k + 1
    Else
        foundrow = sht2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=sht.Cells(i, 1).Value).Row

        On Error Resume Next
        foundcol = sht2.Range("1:1").Find(What:="Question # " & sht.Cells(i, 3).Value).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        If foundcol = 0 Then
            lastcol = sht2.Cells(1, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            sht2.Cells(1, lastcol + 1).Value = "Question # " & sht.Cells(i, 3).Value
            sht2.Cells(foundrow, lastcol + 1).Value = sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Else
            sht2.Cells(foundrow, foundcol).Value = sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: fantastic! it works beautifully. you sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.